# Use custom pipe in multiple modules without sharedModule

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer, angular2-custom-pipes

Is it possible to use **CustomPipe** in lazy modules **without** using common or **shared** modules. I don't want to write pipe for every module.

Below is my CustomPipe.ts

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'bypassHtml'
})

export class BypassHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: any): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can, for example, create a Module with only this pipe and import it in every lazy module.

Comment: @PatrykBłaziński, thanks for replying. I already tried that you saying and its working 
 but I don't want to create an extra module for doing this.